# Show page for few seconds and navigate to another page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to show page A for 5 seconds and navigate to page B ? I am building a POS application. It has to show approved transaction screen for few seconds and navigate to print receipt screen automatically after 5 seconds. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

use a timer:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000), () =>
        {
           Navigation.PushAsync(new PageB());
           return false;
        });
```

Comment: what if current page is destroyed (moving to next page) before returning true/false from Func<bool>?

Answer (score 0):

Just put a delay in your code prior to calling the routine to open the new page:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```

or if if you want the screen to lock up whilst the delay is happening, just use the sleep command:

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```